# CellFormating datagrid WPF equivalent, need for unknown column lenght conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting

I have an old program on Winforms where I have a function that after the DatagridView is populated I apply a format using CellFormatting Event on the last column. I can't find an equivalent way of how to do it on WPF.

```
private void Afo_dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        int lastColumn = afo_dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == ultimaColumna)
        {
            decimal money;
            if (decimal.TryParse(afo_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[lastColumn].Value.ToString().Replace("$", string.Empty), out money))
            {
                if (money > 0m)
                {
                    afo_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[lastColumn].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    afo_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[lastColumn].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is really simple but I am struggling finding the equivalent way to do it on WPF since I don't know the column lenght and I need to convert the data to check if it apply.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't know the column length"?

Comment: @Andy it's a dynamic table, where I don't know how many columns it have, but only they last one need to be painted based on a parsed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I came out with a solution at Winforms Style for dynamic column generation (which in my case I can have from 3 to 7 columns).

```
    private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {            
        DataGrid? dataGrid = (sender as DataGrid);
        DataRowView? dataRowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.Item;

        decimal money;
        if (dataRowView is not null && dataGrid is not null && decimal.TryParse(dataRowView.Row.ItemArray[dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1].ToString().Replace("$", string.Empty), out money))
        {
            //Get the desired cell
            DataGridTextColumn? col = dataGrid.Columns[dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1] as DataGridTextColumn;
            if (col is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //Paint the desired foreground
            if (money > 0m)
            {
                col.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#009000"));
            }
            else
            {
                col.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#ff6347"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your window resources or a resource dictionary merged in app.xaml add the following style:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="RedGreenMoneyStyle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={local:MoneyValueToBrushConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
```

Make sure you have an appropriate xmlns for local.

eg my test project is called wpf_Datagrid and I have

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_Datagrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_Datagrid"
```

Add the following converter class:

```
public class MoneyValueToBrushConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double num;
        if (!Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out num))
        {
            return Brushes.Black;
        }
        return num > 0 ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Handle an event after the window is rendered and columns of your datagrid are generated.

In my experiment I have columns I define and no auto generation so I just used datagrid loaded:

```
    private void dg_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Style style = TryFindResource("RedGreenMoneyStyle") as Style;
        DataGridTextColumn col =  dg.Columns[dg.Columns.Count-1] as DataGridTextColumn;
        if (style is not null && col is not null)
        {
            col.ElementStyle = style;
        }
    }
```

The converter takes a string, parses it as a double. Checks whether the result is +- and returns a brush.  Which is used as the textblock foreground.
In a datagridcell when you're not editing it, you will have a textblock.  That turns into a textbox when you edit but changing colour as you type digits comma and decimal place would introduce some complications. The converter has some guards built in to minimise issues but maybe you want to expand on it's functionality.

The binding in the style uses whatever is the text out the textblock as the value as we do not know the bound property/column name.

The code applying the style looks up the resource, grabs whatever the last column is in the datagrid and sets the style on it.

My datagrid is a bit strange as I just added this onto something I have a bunch of other experiments in but it all hangs together.

Zero is red?

[image]

Comment: In my case I have autogenerating columns because I have to perform some calculations, and depending on the calculation can be 3, 4, 5, N columns

Comment: That code finds whatever the last column is @Andres Diaz De Valdes  Doesn't matter if I have a list of columns or autogenerated. It works with whatever is the last column.

Comment: thanks very much for your example, It helped me to achieve the desired results using the WinForms Style.