# Make background of DataGrid cell change colour if value is negative/positive in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Self explanatory question but for further clarity, the text in the cell of the PnL column will be random such as "-423.21" or "73.21". I want it to simply change the cell background green if it is above 0 and red if it is below.

This is what i tried:

```
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PnL" Binding="{Binding PnL}" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PnL}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PnL}" Value="{x:Static sys:Double.MinValue}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PnL}" Value="{x:Static sys:Double.MaxValue}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one converter for the brush property. That can encompass all logic you like for the brush colour.

Here's one I created earlier does just red and green.

This is generic and checks the text of the control but you could bind a specific known property instead.  You could also pass the different brushes as properties of the markupextension.

```
public class MoneyValueToBrushConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double num;
        if (!Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out num))
        {
            return Brushes.Black;
        }
        return num > 0 ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

You use that with the background brush:

```
  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={local:MoneyValueToBrushConverter}}"/>
       </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Here it is working in a datagrid I have:

[image]

Comment: I have implemented your code and it doesn't seem to work for me, is there not a need for a data trigger?

Comment: Not sure what you've done @5hihan but it works ok for me.  This just does red and green as it is. Datatriggers would be an alternative.  Since you know the property name in this case you can bind to that and cast to double instead of parsing the textblock string.  I wrote the converter yesterday for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75393449/cellformating-datagrid-wpf-equivalent-need-for-unknown-column-lenght-conversion/75400718#75400718

Comment: I figured out why it didn't work for me, it was a stupid mistake. I was using System.Drawing instead of System.Windows.Media for the Brushes xD

Answer (score 0):

You could use two value converters for this, a less-than converter and a greater-than converter.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PnL}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PnL, 
                               Converter={StaticResource LessThanConverter}, 
                               ConverterParameter=0" 
                     Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PnL, 
                               Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanConverter}, 
                               ConverterParameter=0" 
                     Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

MSN has documentation on creating converters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data

You could also just use one of the two converters with two triggers for True and False but you would need to make sure your DataTrigger for Value="0" is the last trigger in declared order or you will not get the Orange background when the value is 0.

Comment: No you wouldn't

Comment: If you're going to write a converter then there's not much point in using a datatrigger as well. You already have some code where you can put logic.

Comment: There is little to no chance of reusing a converter that does something as specific as changing a number to a particular color of brush. A more generic converter for less-than or greater-than could be reused in a plethora of situations with minimal xaml code.

Comment: I wrote that converter yesterday for another question. Seems to be a common requirement.

Comment: Except the converter you wrote doesn't match the requirements of the OP. It's supposed to return Orange for the case of 0. The converter you supplied returns red for <= 0. So it's not really being reused here, right? A different converter with different colors and constraints would need to be written. You seem to be missing the bigger picture here that a converter for such a specific set of requirements is not a very reusable converter. My suggestion is simply an alternative, more generic and reusable solution.